# Generic HashMap, unwanted output (C)

Tags: c, pointers, generics, struct, hashmap

I was writing a generic Hashtable library but I keep getting problems while I use functions like the lookup().
The expected output should be:

```
result = thirteen
result = thirteen
result = thirteen
```

but I get:

```
result = thirteen
```

and then it crashes. This problem seems to appear when I call the lookup() function more then one time, in fact if I call lookup() one time the code runs without any problem.

Each time I call the lookup() function, it creates a new HashMap, but I can't see any correlation between having more HashMaps and the problem.
I tried to solve the problem using a free() method between each lookup() function, but the problem kept on appearing.

This is a portion of the original code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

  typedef struct _Association Association;
  typedef struct _HashMap HashMap;
  typedef int (*HashMapCmp)(void*, void*);
  /*
    Hash Map
  */
  struct _HashMap{
    Association** array;
    int number_of_rows;
    int number_of_elements;
    HashMapCmp cmp_key;
  };

  /*
    element of the linked Hash Map
  */
  struct _Association{
    void* key;
    void* value;
    struct _Association* next;
  };

  /*
    hash function
  */
  unsigned int hash(HashMap* map, void* key){
      unsigned int hash_value = 0;
      hash_value = (*(int*)key * 1500) % map->number_of_rows;
      return hash_value;
  }

  /*
    inits a new Hash Map
  */
  HashMap* HashMap_new(int table_size, HashMapCmp cmp_key){
    HashMap* result = (HashMap*) malloc(sizeof(HashMap));
    result->number_of_rows = table_size;
    result->array = (Association**) malloc(sizeof(Association*) * result->number_of_rows);
    result->number_of_elements = 0;
    result->cmp_key = cmp_key;

    for(int i = 0; i < result->number_of_rows; i++){
      result->array[i] = malloc(sizeof(Association*));
      result->array[i] = NULL;
    }
    return result;
  }

  /*
    inserts a new association in my Hash Map
  */
  bool HashMap_insert(HashMap* map, void* key, void* value){
    if(map == NULL)
      return false;
    else{
      int index = hash(map, key);
      Association* as = malloc(sizeof(Association*));

      as->key = key;
      as->value = value;
      as->next = map->array[index];

      map->array[index] = as;
      map->number_of_elements++;

      return true;
    }
  }

  /*
    returns the value of the key passed by parameter
  */
  void* HashMap_lookup(HashMap* map, void* key){
    int index = hash(map, key);
    Association* tmp = map->array[index];

    while(tmp != NULL && map->cmp_key(tmp->key,key) != 0){
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return tmp->value;
  }

  /*
    **************************************
    tests methods
  */

  /*
    int pointer (key)
  */
  int* int_new(int n) {
      int* result = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
      *result = n;
      return result;
  }

  /*
    char* pointer (value)
  */
  char** string_new(char* s) {
      char** result = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*20);
      *result = s;
      return result;
  }

  /*
    Integers comparator -> obj1>obj2 = 1, obj1<obj2 = -1, obj1=obj2 = 0
  */

  static int compare_ints(int* obj1, int* obj2) {
      return *obj1 - *obj2;
  }

  /*
    creation of a 5 elements, high 4, HashMap
  */
  HashMap* create_five_elements_hash_map(){
    HashMap* map = HashMap_new(4, (HashMapCmp) compare_ints);

    HashMap_insert(map, int_new(0), string_new("zero"));
    HashMap_insert(map, int_new(13), string_new("thirteen"));
    HashMap_insert(map, int_new(22), string_new("twentytwo"));
    HashMap_insert(map, int_new(34), string_new("thirtyfour"));
    HashMap_insert(map, int_new(41), string_new("fortyone"));

    return map;
  }
  /*
    looking inside the Hashmap for the element
  */
  void test_lookup(){
    HashMap* map = create_five_elements_hash_map();
    char** str = (char**)HashMap_lookup(map,int_new(13));
    printf("result = %s\n", *str);
  }

  int main(){

    test_lookup();
    test_lookup();
    test_lookup();

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: My guess is that you have a crash. Run your program in a debugger to see if it catches a crash. If not then use the debugger to step through the code statement by statement to make sure it works as intended. Also build your program with verbose warnings and treat the warnings as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: There are a few things that stand out though, like for example the `string_new` function. What is the purpose of creating an array of 20 pointers to strings, and only initialize and use the first element of that array? Not to mention that you only copy the *pointer* `s` not the string that `s` might point to.

Comment: Another thing that stands out, `result->array[i] = malloc(...)` directly followed by `result->array[i] = NULL`.

Comment: I got it, so i should not do malloc() but just  result->array[i] = NULL right ?

Comment: @SamuelMagnano one of your allocation is erroned, see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *HashMap_insert* that line is erroned :

> ```
> Association* as = malloc(sizeof(Association*));
> ```

and must be

```
Association* as = malloc(sizeof(Association));
```

or

```
Association* as = malloc(sizeof(*as));
```

else you allocate memory just for 1 pointer while *Association* needs enough space for 3 pointers, and just after when you set *as* fields you write out of the allocated block with an undefined behavior.

---

If you can install *valgrind* I highly encourage you to use it, for instance if I do on your definition under my PI4 here are a lot of messages :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==6708== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6708== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6708== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6708== Command: ./a.out
==6708== 
==6708== Invalid write of size 4
==6708==    at 0x10628: HashMap_insert (c.c:64)
==6708==    by 0x1081B: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:124)
==6708==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6708==    by 0x10943: main (c.c:143)
==6708==  Address 0x49e2244 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==6708==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6708==    by 0x1060B: HashMap_insert (c.c:61)
==6708==    by 0x1081B: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:124)
==6708==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6708==    by 0x10943: main (c.c:143)
==6708== 
==6708== Invalid write of size 4
==6708==    at 0x10648: HashMap_insert (c.c:65)
==6708==    by 0x1081B: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:124)
==6708==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6708==    by 0x10943: main (c.c:143)
==6708==  Address 0x49e2248 is 4 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==6708==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6708==    by 0x1060B: HashMap_insert (c.c:61)
==6708==    by 0x1081B: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:124)
==6708==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6708==    by 0x10943: main (c.c:143)
==6708== 
==6708== Invalid write of size 4
==6708==    at 0x10628: HashMap_insert (c.c:64)
==6708==    by 0x10843: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:125)
==6708==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6708==    by 0x10943: main (c.c:143)
==6708==  Address 0x49e2334 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==6708==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6708==    by 0x1060B: HashMap_insert (c.c:61)
==6708==    by 0x10843: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:125)
==6708==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6708==    by 0x10943: main (c.c:143)
...
```

but after the correction :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==6844== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6844== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6844== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6844== Command: ./a.out
==6844== 
result = thirteen
result = thirteen
result = thirteen
==6844== 
==6844== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6844==     in use at exit: 1,596 bytes in 66 blocks
==6844==   total heap usage: 67 allocs, 1 frees, 2,620 bytes allocated
==6844== 
==6844== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6844==    definitely lost: 108 bytes in 18 blocks
==6844==    indirectly lost: 1,488 bytes in 48 blocks
==6844==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6844==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6844==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6844== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6844== 
==6844== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==6844== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

so you do not have undefined behavior anymore, but that does not means now the program does what you want, and but as you can see you have memory leaks, I encourage you to solve them, and to have more about them :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=definite ./a.out
==6967== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6967== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6967== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6967== Command: ./a.out
==6967== 
result = thirteen
result = thirteen
result = thirteen
==6967== 
==6967== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6967==     in use at exit: 1,596 bytes in 66 blocks
==6967==   total heap usage: 67 allocs, 1 frees, 2,620 bytes allocated
==6967== 
==6967== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 16 of 57
==6967==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6967==    by 0x1073F: int_new (c.c:96)
==6967==    by 0x108FF: test_lookup (c.c:137)
==6967==    by 0x10943: main (c.c:143)
==6967== 
==6967== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 17 of 57
==6967==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6967==    by 0x1073F: int_new (c.c:96)
==6967==    by 0x108FF: test_lookup (c.c:137)
==6967==    by 0x10947: main (c.c:144)
==6967== 
==6967== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 18 of 57
==6967==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6967==    by 0x1073F: int_new (c.c:96)
==6967==    by 0x108FF: test_lookup (c.c:137)
==6967==    by 0x1094B: main (c.c:145)
==6967== 
==6967== 16 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 37 of 57
==6967==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6967==    by 0x1056F: HashMap_new (c.c:47)
==6967==    by 0x107EF: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:122)
==6967==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6967==    by 0x10943: main (c.c:143)
==6967== 
==6967== 16 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 38 of 57
==6967==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6967==    by 0x1056F: HashMap_new (c.c:47)
==6967==    by 0x107EF: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:122)
==6967==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6967==    by 0x10947: main (c.c:144)
==6967== 
==6967== 16 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 39 of 57
==6967==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6967==    by 0x1056F: HashMap_new (c.c:47)
==6967==    by 0x107EF: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:122)
==6967==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6967==    by 0x1094B: main (c.c:145)
==6967== 
==6967== 512 (16 direct, 496 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 55 of 57
==6967==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6967==    by 0x104F7: HashMap_new (c.c:40)
==6967==    by 0x107EF: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:122)
==6967==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6967==    by 0x10943: main (c.c:143)
==6967== 
==6967== 512 (16 direct, 496 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 56 of 57
==6967==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6967==    by 0x104F7: HashMap_new (c.c:40)
==6967==    by 0x107EF: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:122)
==6967==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6967==    by 0x10947: main (c.c:144)
==6967== 
==6967== 512 (16 direct, 496 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 57 of 57
==6967==    at 0x4847690: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==6967==    by 0x104F7: HashMap_new (c.c:40)
==6967==    by 0x107EF: create_five_elements_hash_map (c.c:122)
==6967==    by 0x108F3: test_lookup (c.c:136)
==6967==    by 0x1094B: main (c.c:145)
==6967== 
==6967== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6967==    definitely lost: 108 bytes in 18 blocks
==6967==    indirectly lost: 1,488 bytes in 48 blocks
==6967==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6967==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6967==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6967== 
==6967== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==6967== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```